# Secure way of persisting an auth token in a single page js application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

Our scenario:

Our solution consists of an MVC app which serves a single page javascript application, and an Asp.Net WebAPI app which is intended for use both as a standalone api and as a source of data for the SPA.

We have set everything up so that the two apps will share auth tokens and membership, so if we are logged in to the SPA then the same formsauthentication cookie will also allow us access to the API.

This works fine if you make API requests in the browser address bar, but not through AJAX. We have followed examples of setting up basic authentication using Thinktecture and if we hardcode username\password as an authentication header for our ajax calls then this works fine also.

My question is however, what is the correct way of persisting these details on the client side? Our only real solution so far would be to send down the base 64 hash of the username\password as part of the initial load of the SPA and then pull this out when needed. This seems insecure however.

So basically, just wondering what the 'correct' approach is in this situation... are we close or is there another approach that we have overlooked?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you look at ThinkTecture Identity? It has whole host of options.

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks yes we are already using TTI but it was just a case of understanding exactly how we were supposed to use the auth token and persist it on the client. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you're using a forms authentication cookie, why is this not also being sent in AJAX calls?  Is the WebAPI app hosted on a different domain?

Comment: Yes simbolo, thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

We're using the session token support from Thinktecture.IdentityModel and then making the token available to the client via a dynamically generated script.

Full details at http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/dog-fooding-our-api-authentication

I also published a sample application demonstrating these concepts at https://github.com/benfoster/ApiDogFood.